# SQL Checking for similar items more than once

Tags: sql, join

Schemas

```
Movie(title, year, director, budget, earnings)
Actor(stagename, realname, birthyear)
ActedIn(stagename, title, year, pay)
CanWorkWith(stagename, director)
```

Looking for movie titles that have been used more than once (SQL Robot DEATH MACHINE 2001, 2002, 2039)

```
SELECT M.title
FROM Movie A
LEFT JOIN Movie M ON M.title = A.title AND A.year <> A.year
WHERE M.title IS NULL
```

So it will show titles of movies when it finds another title that has been used in a different year

Comment: Will there be same movie titles in the same year? Or are movie titles unique per year?

Comment: You should leave the original question up so that anyone looking at this knows what the answer goes to.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    title
FROM
    Movie
GROUP BY
    title
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: This works if the movie titles are unique per year. Unfortunately, that information was not disclosed by the OP.

Comment: @AlexR. This will work if there are two movies with the same title in the same year because the results are grouped by `title`. The value of the year column isn't considered in the query logic.

Comment: @AdamPorad, but the question asks for the count of movies that exist more than once but in *different* years(at least the second part of the question does). If there is the same movie title in the same year twice, it will show up in the result set when it shouldn't. Like Alex said, we do not know if the title can also have the same year... in which case, I will modify my answer to utilize a `JOIN`

Comment: @AlexR. and Zane Bien: you're right the question is ambiguous about whether the movies with same title and year should appear in the results.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL 2008r2 and that movies are unique based on Title,Year,Director then:

```
;with cte as (
    Select *, count(*) over(partition by Title) dups
    From movie
)
Select * 
From cte
Where dups> 1
```

Returns all movies titles that have been used more than once.  If you want to limit it to movies in the same year with the same title, just add it to the partition by.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select M.Title
From Movie As M
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From Movie As M1
                Where M1.Title = M.Title
                    And M1.Year <> M.Year
                )
```